# How to insert multiple rows of a tableview, when selected, to core data with Swift 4?

Tags: ios, core-data, swift4

I have two connected problems.

The first is - I’m trying to save selected items from a tableview into core data when the user clicks next, but I want to avoid duplications. However, if the items are already in core data, they need to be shown as already selected - then if the user deselects the row, it deletes that item from core data.

The second is - I’ve got a save function in my model that takes the name of the item and the name of the picture related to that item in the parenthesis and I want to use that in my tableview controller, to save the selected items as mentioned above, but I’m having trouble accessing the specific values. I thought of using `cell.itemName[indexPath.row]` but that doesn’t seem to exist.

Here is the save function:

```
func save(result_name: String, result_theme: String, result_pic: String, existing: ClothesResults?) {
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "ClothesResults", in: managedContext)

    let result = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: managedContext) as! ClothesResults
    result.setValue(result_name, forKey: "resultName")
    result.setValue(result_pic, forKey: "resultPic")
    resultsDB.append(result)

    update()
}
```

I thought of using an if statement in the prepareForSegue function in my tableviewcontroller like (pseudo code):

```
if !row exists {
    insert into core data somehow
}
```

Comment: You should at least add the code related to issue #1.

Comment: I did, that's what the pseudo code is. I'm not sure how to complete it.

Comment: Normally the data you have in the table view comes from the core data persistence store, am I correct to assume that this is not the case here and that your table view has data from somewhere else? If you want to check if an item already exists in Core data, what is the unique identifier?

Comment: Hi Joakim, thanks for helping me. I've got the data for the table view hard coded into core data and I need the selections to go into another entity that's been set up to hold items from different categories. I was thinking of putting the save function into didSelectRow or something, but I'm not sure if this will work or if it's even correct.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.